# Why do i get socket timeout error in kivy android app

Tags: python, sockets, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

I am making app for real time detection of some object and detecting when was last time it moved. I made python object detection and made it server so that it sends frames on mobile kivy app that is showing real time video from server and it shows when was last time it moved. Everything worken until i converted that app to android using buildozer, it gives me server timeout error.
Here is server side :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import socket
import pickle
import struct
from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
from object_detection.utils import visualization_utils as viz_utils
from object_detection.builders import model_builder
from object_detection.utils import config_util

@tf.function
def detect_fn(image):
    image, shapes = detection_model.preprocess(image)
    prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(image, shapes)
    detections = detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)
    return detections

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
data_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_name = socket.gethostname()
host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
print('Host IP:', host_ip)
port = 777
port2= 555
socket_address = (host_ip,port)
data_address = (host_ip, port2)

server_socket.bind(socket_address)
data_socket.bind(data_address)

TF_RECORD_SCRIPT_NAME = 'generate_tfrecord.py'
LABEL_MAP_NAME = 'label_map.pbtxt'

paths = {
    'CHECKPOINT_PATH': os.path.join('zavrseni modeli', 'model jaje'),
 }

files = {
    'PIPELINE_CONFIG':os.path.join('zavrseni modeli', 'model jaje', 'pipeline.config'),
    'LABELMAP': os.path.join('zavrseni modeli', 'model jaje', 'label_map.pbtxt')
}

configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(files['PIPELINE_CONFIG'])
detection_model = model_builder.build(model_config=configs['model'], is_training=False)

ckpt = tf.compat.v2.train.Checkpoint(model=detection_model)
ckpt.restore(os.path.join(paths['CHECKPOINT_PATH'], 'ckpt-31')).expect_partial()


category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index_from_labelmap (files['LABELMAP'])
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

server_socket.listen(5)
data_socket.listen(5)
print("LISTENING AT: ",socket_address)
print("LISTENING AT: ",data_address)
client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
client_data, addr2 = data_socket.accept()
print('GOT CONNECTION FROM: ', addr)
print('GOT CONNECTION FROM: ', addr2)
ko=0
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    image_np = np.array(frame)
    if image_np is not None:

        input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
        detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)
        if detections is not None :
            num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
            detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
                              for key, value in detections.items()}
            detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

            detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

            label_id_offset = 1
            image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

            viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                image_np_with_detections,
                detections['detection_boxes'],
                detections['detection_classes'] + label_id_offset,
                detections['detection_scores'],
                category_index,
                use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                max_boxes_to_draw=1,
                min_score_thresh=.7,
                agnostic_mode=False)

            a = pickle.dumps(image_np_with_detections)
            message = struct.pack("Q", len(a)) + a
            client_socket.sendall(message)
            cv2.imshow("Detections",image_np_with_detections)

            min_score_thresh = .7
            threshold = 0.5
            max_scores = max(detections['detection_scores'])
            for i in range(num_detections):
                box = detections['detection_boxes'][i]
                score = detections['detection_scores'][i]
                if score > .7:
                    ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = box.tolist()
                    pos = ymin + ymax + xmax + xmin
                    print("POS:", pos)
                    print("KO: ",ko)
                    x = abs(pos-ko)
                    print(x)
                    if x>0.05:
                        print("Poslato")
                        client_data.send(str(5).encode())
                        ko = pos
                    else :
                        print("nije poslato")
                        ko = pos
                else :
                    client_data.send(str(0).encode())
        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            client_socket.close()
            client_data.close()
            break
```

Here is client, kivy side :

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy import platform
         
import socket
import cv2
import pickle
import struct
from datetime import datetime

if platform=="android":
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
    request_permissions([Permission.INTERNET])

class Angelus(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.text= "CONNECT"

        self.image = Image()
        layout.add_widget(self.image)
        self.button = MDRaisedButton()
        self.label = MDLabel(text=self.text,
                             adaptive_height = True,
                             halign='center', valign='middle')

        layout.add_widget(self.label)

        self.counter = 0
        self.client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.data_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.host_name = socket.gethostname()
        #self.host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(self.host_name)
        self.host_ip = "192.168.56.1"
        self.port = 777
        self.port2 = 555
        self.client_socket.connect((self.host_ip, self.port))
        self.data_socket.connect((self.host_ip, self.port2))
        self.data = b""
        self.payload_size = struct.calcsize("Q")

        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.update_data(self.data_socket), 1/2)
        Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.update_frame(self.client_socket), 1.0 / 30.0)

        return layout

    def update_frame(self, dt):

        while len(self.data) < self.payload_size:
            packet = self.client_socket.recv(4 * 1024)
            if not packet: break
            self.data += packet
        packet_msg_size = self.data[:self.payload_size]
        self.data = self.data[self.payload_size:]
        msg_size = struct.unpack("Q", packet_msg_size)[0]

        while len(self.data) < msg_size:
            self.data += self.client_socket.recv(4 * 1024)
        frame_data = self.data[:msg_size]
        self.data = self.data[msg_size:]

        frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)

        buffer = cv2.flip(frame, 0).tobytes()
        texture = Texture.create(size=(frame.shape[1], frame.shape[0]), colorfmt='bgr')
        texture.blit_buffer(buffer, colorfmt='bgr', bufferfmt='ubyte')
        self.image.texture = texture

    def update_data(self, dt):
        data2 = str(self.data_socket.recv(1024).decode())
        self.counter= self.counter +1
        print(data2[0])
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        if (self.counter==1):
            self.label.text="CONNECTED"
            self.label.size_hint_x = None
            self.label.width = self.label.texture_size[0]
            data2 = []
        elif data2[0] == "5":
            self.label.text = "MOVED AT: " + current_time
            self.label.size_hint_x = None
            self.label.width = self.label.texture_size[0]
            data2 = []   

Angelus().run()
```

and here is buildozer spec file :

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Angelius

# (str) Package name
package.name = Angelius

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd,opencv,datetime

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
#icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
#icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host
```

I used scrcpy and adb logcat -s python to see logs and gives me timeout error.
I also tried on 2 diffirent phones same error, btw platform is android.
Ip and ports are good as you can see, and i also thought that there is some error im my kivy app so i made one test app that just connects sockets and it was same error.

Comment: The ports you are using are privileged. Try using port numbers above 1023.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your server and client are using the same `ip` address for the connection?

Comment: Yes both use same `ip` 100% sure. I changed ports to `1055` and `1077` same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So error was that for someone reason i got 2 IPv4 address or like 2 ports and my phone can't 'see' one that `host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)` is giving but rather other one that i got using `ipconfig` in cmd. Now it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).